# render_to_response() - KeyError: 'object'

Tags: django, django-views

I'm working on Django. I'm getting the error below. I didn't find the solution despite the much increased. I'd appreciate it if you could help.

/core/views.py

```
class CreateVote(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
form_class = VoteForm

def get_initial(self):
    initial = super().get_initial()
    initial['user'] = self.request.user.id
    initial['movie'] = self.kwargs[
        'movie_id'
    ]
    return initial

def get_success_url(self):
    moive_id = self.object.moive.id
    return reverse(
        'core:MovieDetail',
        kwargs = {
            'pk':moive_id
        }
         )    
def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
    movie_id = context['object']
    movie_detail_url = reverse(
        'core:MovieDetail',
        kwargs = {'pk':movie_id }
    )

    return redirect(
        to=movie_detail_url)
```

I could not find movie.id from render_to_response returns context dic.

[image: error page]

[image: Traceback screen- print]

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

A `CreateView` basically is used twice in the creation process:

1. once to construct the form to create the object, in which case, there is *no* created object yet; and
2. once for the POST that will construct the object.

There are two cases where `render_to_response` is called:

1. when we perform a GET, and thus create the the form, at which point there is no object, (`self.object = None`, so that means it is *not* added to the context data); and
2. when we perform a POST, and the form turns out to be *invalid*, in that case the form is typically rerendered with the error.

You can use [**`self.object`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView.object) to access the object that is creates, but as said before, it is rather *non-sensical* here to access it, since `render_to_response`, is used to render a form in case it was not filled in yet, or filled in with errors.

Typically one specifies the template that *renders* the form, for example like:

```
class CreateVote(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = VoteForm
    template_name = 'app/some_template.html'

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['user'] = self.request.user.id
        initial['movie'] = self.kwargs['movie_id']
        return initial

    def get_success_url(self):
        movie_id = self.object.moive.id
        return reverse('core:MovieDetail', kwargs = {'pk': movie_id })

    # no render_to_response override
```